# Why do I get "Call to a member function on null" error in CodeIgniter with call from Controller to Library function?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to call a library function from my controller, but getting an error

> Exception: Call to a member function items_upload() on null /usr/local/www/public_html/pos_clcdesq/application/controllers/Config.php 1022

I think this error usually means that the controller doesn't have access to the library function, but as you can see from my constructor, I loaded the library.  What am I missing here?

Controller constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct('config');

    $this->load->library('barcode_lib');
    $this->load->library('sale_lib');
    $this->load->library('Clcdesq_integration_lib');
}
```

Controller initial_items_upload function:

```
public function initial_items_upload()
{
    $this->Clcdesq_integration_lib->items_upload();
}
```

Library constructor and items_upload function:

```
class Clcdesq_integration_lib
{
private $CI;
private $api_key;
private $api_url;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct($api_key = '')
{
    $this->CI =& get_instance();

    $this->api_key  = $this->CI->encryption->decrypt($this->CI->Appconfig->get('clcdesq_api_key'));
    $this->api_url  = $this->CI->encryption->decrypt($this->CI->Appconfig->get('clcdesq_api_url'));
}

public function items_upload()
{
    $all_items = json_decode(json_encode($this->CI->Item->get_all(), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE), true);

    foreach($all_items as $item)
    {
        $item_data[] = json_decode(json_encode($this->CI->Item->get_info($item['item_id']), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE), true);
    }

    $pushdata   = $this->populate_api_data($item_data);

    if (version_compare(phpversion(), '7.1', '>='))
    {
        ini_set( 'precision', 17 );
        ini_set( 'serialize_precision', -1 );
    }

    $json = json_encode($pushdata, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

    $clcdesq_guid = $this->send_data($this->api_url, $this->api_key, $json);

    log_message("ERROR", "New Product JSON Results: $json");
    log_message("ERROR", "API Results: $clcdesq_guid");
}
```

I'm calling the function from the view:

```
        <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
            <?php echo form_label($this->lang->line('config_clcdesq_utilities'), 'config_clcdesq_items_upload', array('class' => 'control-label col-xs-2')); ?>
            <div class='col-xs-2'>
                <div id="items_upload" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                    <span style="top:22%;"><?php echo $this->lang->line('config_clcdesq_items_upload'); ?></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

$("#items_upload").click(function() {
    window.location='<?php echo site_url('config/initial_items_upload') ?>';
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had some problems in the past with libraries starting with uppercase. Change to lowercase (file name + how you load the library in controller) and see what happens.

Comment: This fixed the problem.  Like all other libraries, the physical file begins with the capital letter, and the class begins with a capital letter, but the calls themselves needed to be lowercase.  This resolved the problem. Thank you.